# How to measure distance between two point in an image and directly save in a sheet?

Tags: image, excel, distance, measure, imagej

I am in need to measure the distance between two point in an radiographyimage acquired (many) so i need a software that do save the distance between two point in a sheet automatically.
I found an opensource software ImageJ that maybe can help me do this work.
this [ImageJ Home page](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/index.html)

What i need also is that the line that I draw between the two point is memorized on the image.
I see at a very first look that the program calculate the distance between one point that i draw and the zero cordinate and memorize it on a sheet.

so i think that it can handle my need of measuring distance between two point and store in a sheet, just need to know if there is a way to do it or a plugin that can do this.

Thanks alot

edited

P.S. Like a Two Point-by-Point measurement

or better

a **Line by line measurement** automated on every line it must memorize the lenght in result and label the line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you mean a 2D image or a 3D image stack, but in either case you could use the 3D distance macro for ImageJ:

- [3D Distance Tool](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/tools/3D-Distance-Tool.txt)

The distances between successive clicks are saved to the results table, and then you can save the results table as a `.xls` file that you can load into a spreadsheet.

Comment: I use x-ray radiography .
Anyway. What this 3D Distance Tool go near to what i need but i whold pe good if.
1)the first click is not taken in consideration on the result sheet but just draw  the [1] on the image 
2) If the Third click just clean the cordinate or set a ne starting point for the fourth click to happen (but also draw the [3] on the image
and so on and on
it like 
1)Click >drawpoint
2)CLick > measure the distance from the first click and draw point and put in result
3)Click >set a new beginning and draw but without put in result sheet
4)Click >Drawpoint ,and put result on sheet

Comment: or a macro where the measure come from the drwing of a straight line and the automatic memorization like in the Plugin>Analize>Measure and Label command just automatized and one time costumizable where you choose first the line width for every straight line you draw.
that would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Ok i discovered the ROI Manager inside Imagej and if not completely automated it does the job just by clicking "t" after every line you draw on image it store the cordinate and then save to the rersult sheet.